# Sklearn logistic regression prediction model issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to predict the probability of whether or not an incident IS_Slight based on the time of day. However, I have a feeling I have taken a wrong step somewhere as my confusion matrix in both MultinomialNB and LogisticRegression is producing some weird results, ie only False Positive and True Positives. I feel like there should be some True Negatives and False Negatives. The low roc_auc_score is also throwing me off, should it not be high ?. I know this is a lot to look through but thank you for any advice.

```
#if word slight found then set to 1 else set to 0
df['IS_SLIGHT'] = df['Accident_Severity'].apply(lambda x: 1 if 'Slight' in x else 0)

cvec = CountVectorizer()
X = df.Time
y = df.IS_SLIGHT
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=1)

cvec = CountVectorizer()
cvec.fit(X_train)
RT_train = pd.DataFrame(cvec.transform(X_train).todense(),columns=cvec.get_feature_names())
RT_test = pd.DataFrame(cvec.transform(X_test).todense(),columns=cvec.get_feature_names())

print(RT_train)
```

Out:

```
      afternoon   evening   morning   night  
 --- ----------- --------- --------- ------- 
  0           0         1         0       0  
  1           0         1         0       0  
  2           0         0         1       0
```

...

```
print(RT_train.shape)
```

Out: (1390029, 4)

```
print(RT_test.shape)
```

Out:(463344, 4)

```
print(y_train.shape)
```

Out:(1390029,)

```
print(y_test.shape)
```

Out:(463344,)

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(RT_train,y_train)

lrypred = lr.predict(RT_test)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, lrypred))
```

Out: 0.8502969715805104

```
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, lrypred))
```

Out:
    [[     0  69364]
     [     0 393980]]

```
nb = MultinomialNB()

nb.fit(RT_train,y_train)
ypred = nb.predict(RT_test)

print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,ypred))
```

Out: 0.8502969715805104

```
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,ypred))
```

Out: [[     0  69364]
 [     0 393980]]

```
y_pred_prob = nb.predict_proba(RT_test)[:,1]
lry_pred_prob = lr.predict_proba(RT_test)[:, 1]
print(y_pred_prob)
```

Out: [0.85453109 0.85453109 0.78504675 ... 0.85453109 0.78504675 0.86917669]

```
print(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,y_pred_prob))
```

Out: 0.5436548840102361

```
print(metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test,lry_pred_prob))
```

Out: 0.5436548840102361

```
print(classification_report(y_test, lrypred))
```

Out:

```
                 precision   recall     f1-score      support  
 -------------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ---------- 
  0                   0.00       0.00         0.00      69364  
  1                   0.85       1.00         0.92     393980  
  micro avg           0.85       0.85         0.85     463344  
  macro avg           0.43       0.50         0.46     463344  
  weighted avg        0.72       0.85         0.78     463344
```

Comment: Seems like your dataset is imbalanced. Use `stratify` in `train_test_split` to get a balanced split between both classes in train and test.

Comment: `train_test_split(X,y,random_state=1, stratify=y)` yields this `[[    0  69392] [     0 393952]]`. So not much difference, unless I used stratify wrong.

Comment: LR is a classification model